# Is there any way I can read the geojson properties in openlayers 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, geojson

So I'm trying to read some data from some geojson which I think is quite possible. The thing is I'm stucked.

My code is very simple. This is my vector-source and this is how I render my geojson :

```
            var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                url: 'some_geojson_is_here'
            });
```

Then I pass this vectorSource as a source to a vector layer etc etc. Now I'm wondering is there any way I can get every feature this geojson has??

In this link : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html the 3-rd method it's what I think the way to get all features but I couldn't figure out how to use it. Any idea guys? Any idea, or help would be highly appreciated :) !

Answer (score 0):

Once loaded the features can be accessed in the layer using vectorSource.getFeatures().
See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getFeatures